# PHP: Extract using regex, preg_match() function

Tags: regex, preg-match

I want to extract the numbers `3` and `2` using `preg_match()`

```
[{"id":"3","value":"2"}]
```

These numbers won't be the same every time, it'll be generated depending on witch page the user is viewing.

Comment: Use `preg_match('(\d+)\D+(\d+)', $str, $m);` and check `$m[1]` and `$m[2]`

Answer (score 2):

The data appears to be JSON. As such, do not use Regular Expressions, use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode).

```
print_r(json_decode($yourdata, true));
```

Comment: He's asking to extract the data, not print it.

Comment: The example was provided as demonstration. However undeserved, I do appreciate you leaving a comment with your down vote.

Comment: I felt like all the votes given to you we're somewhat unreasonable as he seems to ask very specific about the extraction of the data and also using preg_match (something I actually didn't include as well). In that sense, if Ωmega is right, he should get all the credit.

Comment: To each their own. I don't believe in downvoting. As far as the votes I received, the community seems to feel differently than you... `preg_match` is not the proper solution here.

Comment: I'll leave that to the author of the question. Sometimes what may seem to look like a proper answer to the community may not be what is intended in the context of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are trying to extract is JSON. If you want to use preg_match, you can use Ωmega-'s solution (which I corrected a small bit '/'-slashes we're not included):

```
$str = '[{"id":"3","value":"2"}]';
preg_match('/(\d+)\D+(\d+)/', $str, $json_object);
$id = $json_object[1];
$value = $json_object[2];
echo $id;
echo $value;
```

If parsing JSON is what you're after:

```
$string = '{"id":"3","value":"2"}';
$json_dec = json_decode($string, true);
$id = $json_dec['id'];
$value = $json_dec['value'];
echo $id;
echo $value;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. Thanks also to @Ωmega and Jason McCreary for providing their insight.

Comment: I see your new to this website. You can mark one of the answers as the 'answer' to your own question. This helps the other users to no longer needing to view this question.